# Test PubsubIO read with local emulator

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I was able to setup `TestPipeline` and `PubsubIO` to work with `Pubsub` emulator:

```
  options = TestPipeline.testingPipelineOptions().as(PubsubOptions.class);
  options.setPubsubRootUrl(pubsubUrl);
```

but the problem is how to bound `PubsubIO.readMessages()` when unit testing, to actually have a finite test:

```
  final PCollection<PubsubMessage> pCollection =
      pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromTopic("some-topic"));

  PAssert.that(pCollection).satisfies(pubsubMessages -> {
    pubsubMessages.forEach(System.out::println);
    return null;
  });

  pipeline.run();
```

I'm using `google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all` version `2.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

With Direct runner, as far as I'm aware, this is currently not possible (which, I agree, is very unfortunate).

With Dataflow runner, your best bet would probably be to programmatically initiate a Drain on the pipeline after some amount of time.